# How do I host my community as a subdirectory rather than subdomain?

Tags: seo, google, subdomain, subdirectory, community

I want to harness the SEO benefits of having my community portal sitting as a folder of my main domain, rather than as a subdomain.
A lot of the content that is naturally generated is relevant to my main site. By splitting the 2 I am not getting indexed as well as I could by Google.
Unfortunately the software I am using for my community can only offer me domain aliasing, eg.
community.mysite.com 
Does anyone know how I would be able to move this to a subdirectory so that it's mysite.com/community?

Comment: There are no big benifits to a subdirectory vs a subdomain.   If your subdomain content is related to your main content and is authored with the same copyright, Google will treat it as part of the main site just like they would with a folder.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a SaaS you can prob do it like so: Make sure the community app folder is named "community" and lives inside the folder that your TLD is pointing to. Goto mysite.com/community and see if it works. If it doesn't, change the configs/settings in the community app to use the new URL scheme. Once its all linked and loaded, make a 301 redirect to fire requests for `community.mysite.com/*` to `mysite.com/community/*`. You can redirect with vhosts, htaccess, or even do it with `location` header in your codebase. Although the redirect would take care of it, you should also cruise through the DB and templates to change sources to the new URL scheme.

Hope that works out for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a SaaS, so it appears I will have to use a subdomain.

Comment: @walbuc Ah i see. You can prob still point it using a subdomain "A" record then pick up the request and mask it as subdir. But as Stephen said, it really won't affect anything as far as ranking goes. Google is well beyond the days when static mattered.